# What does ([, value]) => value mean ? d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-manipulation

I'm working on d3.js, I am trying to make a stacked circles chart.
I met some new stuff, like functions are defined

```
function myfct (xxx, {parameters}={}){ ... }
```

I interpreted the ", {}" part as the definition of optional parameters (? thanks for any further explanation on that)

My main question however is

```
chart = Pack(rollup, {
  value: ([, value]) => value,
  label: ([key]) => key?.split(/\s+/g).join("\n"),
  title: ([key], n) => `${n.depth 
    ? `${n.ancestors().reverse().slice(1).map(({data: [key]}) => key).join("\n")}\n`
    : ""}${n.value.toLocaleString("en")}`,
  width: 2000,
  height: 2000,
})
```

This is the code they use to call the chart function, I couldn't find someplace to understand the usage of [, value] and [key], so that I can use them for my own case ?
If anyone could explain or point me where to look, would be of much help, thanks !

Comment: That is JavaScript destructuring assignment . Basically they are only interested in the "value" property when they do [,value]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @Amit Not the `value` property. The second element in the array/iterable that is passed as an argument.

Comment: Object destructuring and optional parameters is the only thing going on there. Google search both and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @ivar... Correct. value will hold the second element of the array

Comment: You guys are awesome !